# Issues with Iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I am trying to embed a scratch Project into GitHub pages. I have some code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><head><title>Project-Zero | OS-ONE</title><link rel="icon" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OS-ONE/Project-Zero/main/image2.png" type="image/x-icon"/></head><iframe style="margin-top:-56px; margin-left:-11px;" allowtransparency="false" width="100%" height="108%" bgcolor=#220000 src="https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/embed/468188401/" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

But for some reason it displays like this:
[image: img]
Is there a way to fix this? I have seen others with the same issue as me, but for some reason it doesn't work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try settings the width/height to pixels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with with/height set in pixels and max-with:100% to iframe.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><head><title>Project-Zero | OS-ONE</title><link rel="icon" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OS-ONE/Project-Zero/main/image2.png" type="image/x-icon"/></head><iframe style="max-width: 100%;" allowtransparency="false" width="1000" height="600" bgcolor=#220000 src="https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/embed/468188401/" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```